# Extract information when shell function has completely loaded Solidworks

Tags: vba, shell, solidworks

I'm trying to extract part information from solidworks using VBA in Excel. All stored drawings are in several local folders. The script I'm using cycles through each drawing by loading them from the file dir() command and shell script and then closes the drawing via another macro. The problem is that the shell command acts independently of the VBA code, so it's still loading Solidworks drawings while still running the vba procedure and has a runtime error when loading large drawings. Some drawings take a few minutes to open and some take a few seconds to open.

How can I tell VBA to continue its procedure after the drawing is FULLY loaded?
I've tried Application.wait but with some drawings opening in 3 seconds and others in 3 minutes I'm hoping for a better solution than waiting more than 3 minutes for each drawing.

I thought there might be something in the createprocess windows.api but I'm unsure of how to manipulate it to my situation. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/Concepts/Windows-API/determine-when-a-shelled-process-ends

```
Public Sub OverallFilePathReferncer()


Dim FSOLibrary As Object
Dim FSOFolder As Object
Dim folderName As String
Range("a2").Select
'Set the folder name to a variable
folderName = "<general_filepath_here\>"

'Set the reference to the FSO Library
Set FSOLibrary = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Another Macro must call LoopAllSubFolders Macro to start
LoopAllSubFolders FSOLibrary.GetFolder(folderName)

End Sub


Sub LoopAllSubFolders(FSOFolder As Object)

Dim FSOSubFolder As Object
Dim FSOFile As Object

'For each subfolder call the macro
For Each FSOSubFolder In FSOFolder.SubFolders
    LoopAllSubFolders FSOSubFolder
Next

'For each file, print the name
For Each FSOFile In FSOFolder.Files
If Right(FSOFile.Path, 7) = ".SLDDRW" Then

ActiveCell = FSOFile.Path
'ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3) = FSOFile.Name

CreateObject("Shell.Application").Open (FSOFile.Path)
Set swApp = CreateObject("SldWorks.Application")
swApp.Visible = True


DoEvents
Call CloseOtherWindows
Call PartNumbGrab

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = PartNo
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) = PartName
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Debug.Print FSOFile.Path
End If

Next

End Sub
```

My CloseOtherWindow macro

```
#If VBA7 Then
 Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "User32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
#Else
 Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "User32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
#End If

Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks

Sub CloseOtherWindows()


Set swApp = CreateObject("SldWorks.Application")

Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2

Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc

If Not swModel Is Nothing Then
    
    Dim vDocsWindows As Variant
    
    Dim swFrame As SldWorks.Frame
    Set swFrame = swApp.Frame
    
    vDocsWindows = swFrame.ModelWindows
    
    Dim i As Integer
    
    For i = 0 To UBound(vDocsWindows)
        
        Dim swDocWin As SldWorks.ModelWindow
        Set swDocWin = vDocsWindows(i)
        
        Dim swRefDoc As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
        Set swRefDoc = swDocWin.ModelDoc
        
        If Not swRefDoc Is swModel Then
            If swRefDoc.GetSaveFlag() Then
                'display the close confirmation dialog for unsaved files
                swApp.ActivateDoc3 swRefDoc.GetTitle, False, swRebuildOnActivation_e.swDontRebuildActiveDoc, 0
                Const WM_COMMAND As Long = &H111
                Const CMD_FileClose As Long = 57602
                SendMessage swFrame.GetHWnd(), WM_COMMAND, CMD_FileClose, 0
            Else
                swApp.CloseDoc swDocWin.ModelDoc.GetTitle
            End If
            
        End If
    Next
    
    swApp.ActivateDoc3 swModel.GetTitle, True, swRebuildOnActivation_e.swUserDecision, 0
    
End If

End Sub
```

My PartNumbGrab macro

```
Option Explicit

Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks
Dim swModel As ModelDoc2
Dim swModelDocExt As ModelDocExtension
Dim swCustProp As CustomPropertyManager
Global PartNo As String
Global PartName As String
Dim val As String
Dim bool As Boolean
Sub PartNumbGrab()
Set swApp = CreateObject("SldWorks.Application")
Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
Set swModelDocExt = swModel.Extension
' Get the custom property data
Set swCustProp = swModelDocExt.CustomPropertyManager("")
bool = swCustProp.Get4("PART_NUMBER", False, val, PartNo)
bool = swCustProp.Get4("PART_NAME", False, val, PartName)


End Sub
```

Comment: I'm wondering why you create several instances of Solidworks (_createObject_) and not use the same instance for all your macro steps.

Comment: I'm a bit confused what shell you are refering to. The tag _shell_ without any further classification (such as _bash_) refers to POSIX shell. If you want to run a Windows shell command from Basic, I suggest that you add either _cmd_ or _powershell_ as additional tag, to make this clear.

Comment: @user1934428 `Shell` is an inbuilt VBA command in all basics except VBScript. It starts a program.

Comment: @Lundt: Good to know. This still makes it a bad idea using the **Stackoverflow tag** _shell_, which has a different meaning.

Comment: @user1934428 Of course. But the question wizard probably suggested it. That means the `shell` tag should be disambiguated.

Comment: @user1934428 And any questions would mostly be about misplaced quote characters or why it starts programs and **doesn't** execute Window's *shell* commands.

Comment: @Lundt : I think the question wizard mostly scans for the occurance of certain words. If I mention in my question that my colleagues at work already bash me because I can't get my Cobol program right, the question wizard will likely suggest _bash_ and _cobol_. We don't expect real AI here, do we?

Comment: @user1934428 I'm just saying don't judge humans on **programmers** criteria who are trying to control people. Both, from their perspective, negatively and positivity.

Answer (score 0):

`WaitForInputIdle` returns when when any of the windows of the specified process are waiting for user input. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-waitforinputidle

Note: The functions are in the User32 library which is the windowing library as you are detecting a window without a queue full of messages which at start up configure windows. Starting a program is in Kernel32 as it doesn't assume windowing.

```
    Public Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, ByVal bInheritHandle As Boolean, ByVal processId As Long) As Long
    Public Declare Function WaitForInputIdle Lib "user32" (ByVal hProcess As Long, ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) As Long

    Public Const AllAccess = &H1F0FFF
    Public Const Terminate = &H1
    Public Const CreateThread = &H2
    Public Const VirtualMemoryOperation = &H8
    Public Const VirtualMemoryRead = &H10
    Public Const VirtualMemoryWrite = &H20
    Public Const DuplicateHandle = &H40
    Public Const CreateProcess = &H80
    Public Const SetQuota = &H100
    Public Const SetInformation = &H200
    Public Const QueryInformation = &H400
    Public Const QueryLimitedInformation = &H1000
    Public Const Synchronize = &H100000

    Public Const WAIT_TIMEOUT = 258 
    Public Const WAIT_Failed = -1 

Sub Main
        hProcess = OpenProcess(QueryInformation, False, ProcessIDOfSolidWorks)
        Ret = WaitForInputIdle(hProcess, TimeoutMilliSec)
End Sub
```

Adapted from here https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2021/04/waitforinputidleexe-starts-graphical.html